# How to stretch a mesh along a curve

Tags: modeling, modifiers, curve-modifier

I'd like to make my mesh to stretch along a curve. I want it stretches when the curve's control points move, just like how Lattice Modifier can stretch or squash a mesh.

So far I tried:

- Curve modifier: it seems to make a mesh "move" along a curve, but not stretch.
- Array modifier with Fit Curve option: it duplicates the mesh, not stretch it.
- Array modifier with Fit Curve and Merge option: it duplicates the mesh and merge the duplicates into a single mesh, still not stretch it. I don't want to change the topology.

Is it possible to stretch/squash a mesh along a curve? Similar to how other deforming modifiers (Lattice/Mesh/Surface) can stretch meshes?

Comment: maybe you could use shape keys + Curve modifier? But maybe show a screenshot of your object?

Comment: @moonboots it's basically a whip. I want to animate the whip but it's too tedious to set a lot of bones or shape keys. I want to control it with 3 hooks. I know I can use Spline IK... but because I've already made the animation with curve+hooks, I'd like to know if it's possible to just use the curve.

Comment: @moonboots well after thinking twice, Spline IK does use curves so I don't know what I was talking about lol

Comment: Spline IK is a bit painful but yes, you could use it as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for.

[image]

(You would have to fiddle around with the object's location and origin and stuff)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much.